# Cannot push to repository on self-managed GitLab server

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have installed GitLab CE on a CentOS (release 6.10) machine.

After creating the repository from GitLab interface on the browser, I would like to clone and push my changes to the repository.

I tried both cloning the repository and pushing the existing contents to the repository; however, the user password is not accepted although the user's SSH key is registered:

```
# git push -u origin master
git@gitlab.centos6-server.local's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab.centos6-server.local's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab.centos6-server.local's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is the information regarding the setup environment:

```
# gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info

System information
System:     CentOS 6.10
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.7.2p137
Gem Version:    3.1.4
Bundler Version:2.1.4
Rake Version:   13.0.1
Redis Version:  5.0.9
Git Version:    2.29.0
Sidekiq Version:5.2.9
Go Version: unknown

GitLab information
Version:    13.6.7
Revision:   4d1fc8bce72
Directory:  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter: PostgreSQL
DB Version: 11.10
URL:        http://gitlab.centos6-server.local
HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.centos6-server.local/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.centos6-server.local:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: yes
Omniauth Providers: 

GitLab Shell
Version:    13.13.1
Repository storage paths:
- default:  /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
GitLab Shell path:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell
Git:        /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

This is what I get while trying to establish an SSH connection:

```
# ssh -vT git@192.168.6.5
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.6.5 [192.168.6.5] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ayildiz/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ayildiz/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
The authenticity of host '192.168.6.5 (192.168.6.5)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is f6:af:9c:dd:5c:68:ba:26:5d:64:e5:44:5b:50:b6:c8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.6.5' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ayildiz/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@192.168.6.5's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
git@192.168.6.5's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
git@192.168.6.5's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

[image: Account Settings - SSH Keys]

Comment: did you installed gitlab with docker?

Comment: I used the GitLab CE rpm package for the setup.

Comment: could you exec command: `ssh -vT git@{your_gitlab_serverIP}`, and post out the error log?

Comment: I've added the outputs to the original post.

Comment: So you have added a ssh key for your user at https://git.example.com/-/profile/keys, right? That should be sufficient on the server side. On the client side for git to pick up the certificate you need a ssh-agent instance running (`eval $(ssh-agent)`, should print its pid as feedback) and you then need to add the certificate with `ssh-add` (both agent and add are available in the `openssh-clients` package in Fedora).

Comment: eval $(ssh-agent) prints `Agent pid 7534`. I just followed the instructions on GitLab installation manual. I didn't modified any file (do you mean `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/profiles/keys`?) by a specific SSH command. Could you share the exact commands to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

After adding the following lines to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and adding the user `git` to AllowUsers list in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, it no longer prompts for a password:

```
Host gitlab.centos6-server.local 
        RSAAuthentication yes 
        Preferredauthentications publickey 
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Well done, good cactch. Upvoted.

Comment: @VonC This is weird, because I am having the same issue again. Not sure why it happens.

Comment: I switched to HTTPS authentication temporarily.

Comment: OK: does switching to HTTPS explain why you did have the same issue again?

Comment: I just added this comment for information.

Answer (score 0):

> do you mean /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/profiles/keys

No: it means "[adding the public SSH key to your GitLab account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#add-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account)" (the local GitLab, that is, the one running on your CentOS server)

You need to use the web page served by that local GitLab to go to your account setting page and add the public key there.

Comment: I have already added my SSH key via account settings. You can see the respective screenshot above.

Comment: @yildizabdullah Is it the `/home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, and is your private key `/home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: Yes, I copied the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to register my SSH key.

Comment: @yildizabdullah Is the private key protected? (with a passphrase)

Comment: No, there is no passphrase.

Comment: OK, that private key is somehow not recognized by GitLab and its public key: was the public key copied as one line, in its entirety?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is it OK to show `debug1: Offering public key: /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_rsa` but not `debug1: Offering public key: /home/ayildiz/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252922/discussion-between-vonc-and-yildizabdullah).